# npm dependencies not satisfied (even though they should be?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I feel like I must be overlooking something here.

When trying to run npm install on an existing project, I get the following error (from npm-debug.log):

```
76 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
77 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
78 error node v4.4.2
79 error npm  v2.15.0
80 error code EPEERINVALID
81 error peerinvalid The package grunt@0.4.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
81 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-concurrent@0.4.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0
81 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-sass@0.8.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
81 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-autoprefixer@2.0.0 wants grunt@~0.4.2
81 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-webfont@0.5.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0
81 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-purifycss@0.1.1 wants grunt@~0.4.5
82 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

From what I can tell, grunt@0.4.2 should fulfill all these dependencies.

From [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json#_=_), my understanding is that the packages rely on the following:

- grunt-concurrent@0.4.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0 (that is, grunt@0.4.*)
- grunt-contrib-sass@0.8.1 wants grunt@>=0.4.0
- grunt-autoprefixer@2.0.0 wants grunt@~0.4.2 (that is, grunt@0.4.*)
- grunt-webfont@0.5.4 wants grunt@~0.4.0 (that is, grunt@0.4.*)
- Peer grunt-purifycss@0.1.1 wants grunt@~0.4.5 (that is, grunt@0.4.*)

grunt@0.4.2 should match all of these dependencies, and yet npm is saying that it doesn't and failing the install. Is there something I'm overlooking?

On request, my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "glasses-1",
  "siteUrl": "http://www.glasses.com/",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "adaptivejs": "1.3.0",
    "connect": "2.3.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "0.4.3",
    "mocha": "1.14.0",
    "chai": "1.9.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "0.8.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-purifycss": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-webfont": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "description": "This repository contains the code for the glasses-1 Adaptive.js project.",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: can you please share the package.json file?

Comment: I've edited it into the original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`81 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-purifycss@0.1.1 wants grunt@~0.4.5` from second last line

So you need grunt@0.4.5 not 0.4.2

Comment: You're right -- I misunderstood how the tilde worked. Thanks!